# In Eclipse, how can I see all the code I've checked in this week? We use CVS

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I'm using Eclipse 3.3.2 and CVS. Is there a way for me to see the code only I have checked in since some date? I know how to use "Compare With..." to see all the changes (anyone's code) since a particular version or date. Our team doesn't use Task Tags, could those help?

Answer (score 1):

You can create date tags in eclipse. Create a date tag for start of the week then compare the head with this tag. You can create a date tag by switching to cvs browsing perspective then write click on "Dates".

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about Eclipse, but if you have a CVS client installed you can run [CVS rdiff](http://www-e815.fnal.gov/webspace/cvs/commands.html#rdiff) on the command line to get, for example, the files committed between two tags.

One thing I used to do a while back was use Ant for this sort of stuff. You write yourself a script file and call it with appropriate configs. I used the [CvsChangeLog](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/changelog.html) task for that.